# Integration by substitution with involution

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, substitution, change-of-variable

Suppose I use integration by substitution $x' = \phi(x)$
$$
\int_X f(x) dx = \int_{\phi^{-1}(X)} f(x') |\text{det}\phi'(x)| dx'
$$
How does this formula simplify if $\phi$ is an involution $\phi(\phi^{-1}(x)) = \phi^{-1}(\phi(x)) = x$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: @IgorRivin well I think the determinant could probably simplified but honestly that's about it